# Как в Rust читать символ за символом из текстового файла?

Tags: rust

Мне нужно читать из текстового файла символ за символом, как это сделать в Rust без libc и системных вызовов ?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "символом"? `char` представляет кодовую позицию Unicode (не обязательно графему), вам это нужно? Какая кодировка предполагается у текстового файла?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Структура BufReader реализует типаж BufRead, который наследует Read, в котором есть метод read:

```
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    let f = File::open("input.kt").expect("open() failed");
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(f);

    let mut buffer = [0; 1];
    loop {
        match reader.read(&mut buffer) {
            Ok(x) => {
                if x != 0 {
                    println!("{}", buffer[0] as char)
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            Err(y) => panic!("read() failed"),
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Это не даст ожидаемого результата на UTF-8, например, потому что кодовые позиции Unicode могут быть закодированы последовательностью из нескольких байтов.